# Retrieving an object when coming back to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Here's the context of my question :

### Context

I've made a **Recyclerview** that dysplay items thanks to an object called "identity_candle". When I click on items, it brings me to another activity with more description over the item. On this activity, there is a button to view more details about it that needs another layout by itself.
So when I click on the button it lands me on another activity.
**IN SUMMARY**, MainActivity (RecyclerVIew) => ItemActivity => "press button" => **Activity or Fragment ?** (Come back : Activity or Fragment => ItemActivity (keep previous object)

## Problem

But when I want to come back to the previous activity it brings me error because the object state "identity_candle" is null.

### Questions

What should I do ? Should I use fragment instead of activity when I press button ? (I've seen that object keeps their state between fragment and Activity but I'm not sure) Should I use SharedPreference ? If I want to create Fragment should I extends Fragment or ActivityFragment ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems heavily rooted in understanding the [Activity lifecyle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).  You'll likely want to go through that training if you haven't already.  An understanding of `onSaveInstanceState()`, `onRestoreInstanceState()`, and [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)s should get you there.

Comment: Absolutly these things aren't very clear to me. So I will read this, post my answer and you could tell me if I'm right or not ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't use ´onSaveInstanceState´ because the callback ´OnDestroy()´ is called so the bundle saveinstancestate is null. I've choose to use startActivityforResult´ and then put intent when onBackPressed is called. Does it seems to be the correct way ?

Comment: Add what you've tried so far and I'll try to elaborate more.  The purpose of using onSaveInstanceState() is exactly the scenario you're describing, since your Activity will end up being recreated and your instance variables lost if onDestroy() is hit.